# What do repeating css selectors mean when displayed via Google Chrome console log?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Please can someone explain what the issue is when I see a css selector repeated when shown in the Google chrome console log? Why does the second instance have lines through it.

I'm guessing this is a coding error that I will need to fix.

FYI - As per the screen shot below, both .items come from the same css file.

[image]

Comment: And can you check from which line it comes in both cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears because the CSS is found twice in the file.

`crossed out` lines means, that those styles were found but have been overwritten.

To put simply,    <strike>display:block</strike>  like console means that the CSS was applied but then some more *relevant* CSS is found and overwrote the current one.

So for example, if you have markup like :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h2#title{color : red}
            h2#title{color : yellow}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="title"> Hi </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

then, since `h2#title` is found twice in the file, only one can be applied, so, you will see something like this, whichever got overwrote would be *crossed* :

`h2#title{` 
         <strike>`color : red`</strike>   
`}`

**A Good Read on this :** https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles?csw=1&safe=on#computed_style

**Related Helpful Thread :** [Chrome Developer Tools: How to find out what is overriding a CSS rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule)