# CSS selectors repeating multiple times in inspect element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, web-inspector

Before anybody marks it as duplicate I want to say that I have already checked this ["What do repeating css selectors mean when displayed via Google Chrome console log?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377754/what-do-repeating-css-selectors-mean-when-displayed-via-google-chrome-console-lo) but it didn't help because in my case the CSS is written only once in the CSS file but still it show's up multiple times in the inspect element.

I have checked the site in multiple browsers but it has same issue. Here are screenshots I took from:

**CHROME:**

[image: CHROME]

**FIREFOX:** 
[image]

Code inside `HEAD TAG`

```
<head>

<title>ABC INC.</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<meta name="description" content="Global Changes">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<?php set_include_path( get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ); ?>

<link href="/ABC_INC/gchanges/CSS/123.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css">

</head>
```

Comment: Hope your  same css file has been downloaded mulitple times

Comment: Can you show us what is in your <head> part please ?

Comment: Ok and in your <head> part in the browser please ?

Comment: Here: https://i.imgur.com/dE9u9IG.png

Comment: What if you remove the set_include_path() line ?

Comment: Tried removing it but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
You have one (or many) `<link href=''>` tag that refer to **123.css** file inside your `<body>` tag, you have to remove them and keep just one in the `<head>` tag and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent . It's seems like it'd be a days work to get rid of these stupid errors(6 times in each file) in multiple files committed by someone else. I hate my life!

Kidding!