# css .main-navigation ul ul li wordpress category coloring

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi all I would like to change the color of my mega menu items on hover
I am sure that this line changing the above mentioned color

```
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
```

this line changing the mega menu items on hover on every item , but I would like to change just on specific categories example on category 3. I tried different codes but unfortunately they not work

I tired the following solutions without success:

```
.main-navigation .li.vce-cat-3 .ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation .vce-cat-3 .ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation .cat-3 .ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation ul ul li.vce-cat-3:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation ul ul li .vce-cat-3:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation ul ul li vce-cat-3:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
.main-navigation ul ul li.cat-3:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}
```

please help me to solve this problem

I added this additional code that was requested from me

```
<li id="menu-item-945" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-menu-item menu-item-945 vce-mega-cat vce-cat-3"><a href="http://localhost/jasco/?cat=3" data-mega_cat_id="3">Lessons</a><ul class="vce-mega-menu-wrapper">                                    <li>    

        <a class="mega-menu-img" href="http://localhost/jasco/?p=941" title="Electric Guitar Lesson – G Major Scale Technique">
            <img width="375" height="195" src="http://localhost/jasco/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Electric-Guitar-Lesson-G-Major-Scale-Technique-375x195.jpg" class="attachment-vce-lay-b wp-post-image" alt="Electric Guitar Lesson - G Major Scale Technique">                         <span class="vce-format-icon">
                <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
                </span>
                    </a>


    <a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://localhost/jasco/?p=941" title="Electric Guitar Lesson – G Major Scale Technique" style="height: 66px;">Electric Guitar Lesson – G Major Scale Technique</a>

</li>                       
</ul></li>
```

Comment: could we have a full example featuring a fiddle? It may be helpful when trying to fix it.

Comment: I've edited my answer but I totally agree with @James_Parsons that we need a fiddle or a link to a website showing this issue. I do not believe we can provide you the correct answer without the complete html+css+js code. My proposal to use chrome developer tools is still valid, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
.main-navigation .li.vce-cat-3 .ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce !important;}
```

It should do the trick

**EDIT**

please try this, then:

```
.vce-cat-3 li:hover a {color:red!important}
```

*note*: I've set the red color for clarity and I know it is inefficient and a little brutal but it is an attempt to identify the issue without a complete fiddle :-)

Comment: unfortunately this not help either , I think that I dont need the important sign , I just dont know how I need to implement the Category 3 to the next line `.main-navigation ul ul li:hover>a {color:#5c99ce}`

Comment: Then please show us also the HTML code of the menu (the relevant parts). I would also like to suggest you to use a tool like the Chrome Developer Tool in order to inspect the menu element and discover  which  CSS rule is setting the color of the element. Other rules may interfere.

Comment: Thanks furins you did it :) , How can i add a reputation to you ? Sorry I am new here :)