# CSS Filter didnt work - Chrome Inspector strikes trough

Tags: css, wordpress, filter, dropshadow

i have a problem with my website. i want to assign a CSS dropshadow effect to an item but it didnt work. iif i look at the chrome inspector there is a strike trough (see picture). i also tryed the "!important" string after the rule but it is still not working. the same problem is with other filters like greyscale, blur, e.g. on any target (text, picture, div, e.g).

my site is programmed with wordpress and i coded the theme by myself. dont be confused for the text shadow on the right side of the little picture. it was a test. text-shadow and box-shadows are working. but i need a **dropshadow** for the png-files in the table.

why isn't this code working?

thanks for it!

p.s. in the computed style tab i found an entry named "filter". the value for this is "none" (see sceenshot 2). now i'm confused...

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBAb8.png),
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxk4E.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools: How to find out what is overriding a CSS rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-filters , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't \[CSS feature\] work in \[browser\] but works in others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110510/why-doesnt-css-feature-work-in-browser-but-works-in-others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome based on webkit-engine, so you have to use somethink like this.

```
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
```

Comment: that was it! i also tryed "webkit" but forgot the minus before it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That strikethrough typically means you have overriding CSS elsewhere. Check other styles that effect the same tags.