# background-color doesn't apply to my page

Tags: html, css

After styling my css I wanted to add a red background.
Problem is when I add the css to my body it doesn't apply to my page.

Could you tell me what's wrong and why?

You can find my code here: https://codepen.io/jardi/pen/RGNZJV

```css
body {  
  background-color:red;
}

#pageTitle {
  text-align:center;
  font-family:Monospace;
  color: rgb(51,22,225);
  padding:50px;
  font-size:30px;
}

.paraGraphs {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Times New Roman;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
  text-align:justify;
}

#bottom-image{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, the background color is being overridden by the jsFiddle scaffolding here:

```
body { 
        background-color: #FFEEEE;
        color: #004;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    }
```

To test, you can add a !important to your CSS property value like this:

```
body {
  background-color:red !important; /* Prototype code only, !important bad */
}
```

Outside of the jsFiddle, it's almost sure that something else is overriding your body background color (we can't see what). To find out, examine the "computed" CSS for the body element in browser dev tools, to see what.

Reference: [Chrome Developer Tools: How to find out what is overriding a CSS rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule)

Once you see what CSS rule is overriding your background, either remove the offending code, or make sure your selector has more specificity, for example my adding a class:

```
body.myClass {
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Codepen has a scaffolding css with that Bootstrap so it has a bg color of white ...If you do it out of this you will see it and you can doublecheck in codepen by just doing this:

```
body {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

But you wont need that *!important*

**UPDATE**

TO bypass your Bootstrap body bg just add a css file after that OR add inline like so:

```
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="/css/yourfile.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <style>
      body {
      background-color:red;

    }</style>

    </head>
```

Comment: I checked it out of codepen before posting here. I created an html file with the name index.html and linked my css file in my html file. Everything applies but not the background color :/. Did I do something wrong in my css? Should it be in a different order? When I add !important it works but I dont understand why I have to add important

Comment: Its your Bootstrap file..after that file I have that style added or add a css file after that

Comment: great glad that made sense please approve answer @PierreJardinet

Answer (score 0):

You have re-defined background-color for the body after that `background-color: red;`, so add !important, so it can not be overriden:

```
background-color: red!important;
```

Comment: Well it is the inly background-color in my css style so why would I have to override it? Thanks for the advice but I would like to understand :)

Comment: To see what's overriding your rule check out your body element with developer tools like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule .

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by using html body instead of body:

```
html body {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: What does html body do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the link that you attached, your code is using an external CSS:
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

And inside this CSS already have an rule for body...

If you want, just add "!important" in the end of the line to force your color, example:

```
body {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: I see I understand thank you very much :). Well bootstrap should be avoided in the future

Comment: @PierreJardinet: Instead of avoiding bootstrap try adding your bootstrap file to load first and then you can add your own custom css, in that way you can easily override the bootstrap's css.

Comment: "Just add !important" is poor advice for creating maintainable CSS.