# Chrome dev tools: Identifying source of overridden style

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

In developing a web application, I'm having issues identifying the source of CSS style overrides. Based on the answer to this question: [Chrome Developer Tools: How to find out what is overriding a CSS rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule), I attempted to identify the source of the computed style using Chrome's integrated dev tools.

I expected the `border-left-width` property to be 2px, as explicitly defined in the `page_not_found` class rule. The computed style dialog shows the following:

[image: chrome computed style snippet]

Clearly indicating:

- The computed value is `0px`
- The computed value was derived from a single style rule defining an intended value of `2px`

Clearly, `0px` != `2px`, so where is this computed value coming from?

Comment: Try scrolling down on the "computed" window and clicking on the offending style, it should tell you where it's from.

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the issue. The rule for the `border` did not have a `border-style` set, so Chrome recomputed the width to `0px`, with no indication that that was the reason within the computed styles dialog box.