# Not applying style to an element in CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I wrote this CSS so that if the page size is larger than 768 pixels the element I selected will not be displayed, but when I inspect the element there is a line on the style. It is as if another rule or style prevents it from working.

I even checked the linked files and they are all linked correctly!

```css
/* media file */
.nav__btn {
  width: 5.5rem;
  height: 5.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2.2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* application file */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav__btn {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you look at the inspector it is going to show you every style that is being applied to the elements. If more than one conflict, the styles that are being overwritten will have a strikethrough. The CSS that you provided is basically saying nav__btn will have display flex but wait if the screen size is min 768 then override it. But the first will still show because it isn't being told not to by a media query, its just being overwritten

Comment: Please update the demo above with some HTML. CSS is meaningless without it, and we don't have enough information here to help. Also verify page load order of the two rules. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also keep in mind CSS is *cascading* --  Meaning, the order of your media query(s) also matters.

Comment: If you suspect that your rule is overwritten by another rule, you can see in the "computed" section, which rule is ovverriding it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867088/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-find-out-what-is-overriding-a-css-rule

Comment: Also provide the HTML you use as there may be other inline css that we do not see here

Comment: What do you mean by "there is a line on the style?"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```css
@media(min-width: 768px){
  .nav_btn{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! this answer is useful; but I want to know which rule prevented my code from running?